# Missing rows when joining tables

Tags: mysql, inner-join

This problem feels so familiar to me, but I can't get my head around figuring out exactly what I need to modify in the SQL statement to fix it.

Simply put, I have 2 tables - companies and ratings. I want all companies to be listed, even if the company has no ratings, but the query currently only grabs the ones who do. How I can I fix this? I thought it was sufficient to use LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN, but I was wrong.

```
SELECT company.id, company.title, AVG(ratings.ratings)
FROM companies company
INNER JOIN companies_ratings ratings
ON ratings.company_id = company.id
```

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `companies_ratings` (
  `id` int(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `company_id` int(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `ratings` enum('1','2','3','4','5') DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `companies_ratings` (`id`, `company_id`, `ratings`) VALUES
(1, 1, '3'),
(2, 1, '5');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `companies` (
  `id` int(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `companies` (`id`, `title`) VALUES
(1, 'Company 1'),
(2, 'Company 2');
```

Comment: Left join works. Please give a full [mre] that you cut & pasted & ran. [ask] [Help]

Comment: Hi, when running the example code above, it only returns the first company (Company 1).

EDIT: To me it seems like the AVG(ratings.ratings) is part of the problem. If I use LEFT JOIN and add GROUP BY company.id at the end and remove the ratings.ratings from the SELECT part, it fetches both rows.

Comment: EDIT - fixed it by adding GROUP BY company.id at the end. :-)

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. PS The group by is not needed to get every left table row as a subrow in the output. It is needed if you want aggregation per group rather than over the whole table. PS You still don't give a [mre]. Eg you don't say how the result is a function of input, you only say "I want all companies to be listed". PS When giving a relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values.

Comment: The reason why it shows only 1 row is because you're doing an aggregation without `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Note also, that if you had adjusted the sql_mode, attempting to run your SQL would have produced an error (due to functional dependence issues).  The SQL is basically invalid, but MySQL can be configured to allow that invalid use of an aggregate function or invalid use of GROUP BY.

Answer (score 1):

I write this query that worked!

```
(SELECT company.id, company.title, AVG(ratings.ratings)
FROM companies company
left JOIN companies_ratings ratings
ON ratings.company_id = company.id)
union all
(SELECT company.id, company.title, AVG(ratings.ratings)
FROM companies company
left JOIN companies_ratings ratings
ON ratings.company_id = company.id
WHERE ratings.id is null )
```